# Stash get_list set_list

Tags: stash, list, get

I have a page where i want to output some quotes from certain channel within an other entries tag.

It seems to work sofar but stash is outputting the same entry over again, i wanted to use get_list for the unique parameter.

Thanks for your time and effort

Here is my code:

```
     {exp:channel:entries channel="ffq" status="open"}
            {exp:stash:set_list name="quotes"} 
            {stash:quote}{textarea}{/stash:quote} 
            {/exp:stash:set_list}
        {/exp:channel:entries}


         {exp:channel:entries channel="story" orderby="random" category="4" status="open|featured"}
          {other ee stuff}

{if count % 2 == 0}
               {exp:stash:get_list name="quotes" unique="yes"}
                    {quote}
               {/exp:stash:get_list}
{/if}
     {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's outputting the same thing over and over as you've only captured the last 'quote' – you are capturing inside the `{exp:channel…}` tag. So every time EE returns another entry, you are overwriting the last entry. Try instead:

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="quotes" trim="yes' parse_tags="yes"} 
    {exp:channel:entries channel="ffq" status="open"}
        {stash:quote}{textarea}{/stash:quote} 
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}
```

This should at least give you multiple quotes.

As for `{exp:stash:get_list}` what you have currently will output **all** unique quotes and not just unique quotes every 2 iterations. To achieve that will require some thought as you'd likely have use a combination of [offset](https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/%7Bexp%3Astash%3Aget_list%7D#offset---int--fraction-), [limit](https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/%7Bexp%3Astash%3Aget_list%7D#limit---int--fraction) & [slice](https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/%7Bexp%3Astash%3Aget_list%7D#slice---int-offset-int-length-).

---

### **UPDATE**

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="story" orderby="random" category="4" status="open|featured"}
{other ee stuff}

{if count % 2 == 0}
    {exp:stash:get_list 
        name="quotes"
        limit="2" //Limit to 2 Quotes
        offset="{count}" //Your outer count will be 2/4/6/8/etc so we offset the get_list by the same amount.
    }
        {quote}
    {/exp:stash:get_list}
{/if}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Obviously you'll encounter issues if you only on want one quote every 2 outer loops as we're using the outer count but them's the breaks !

Comment: Thanks, that did help a lot. I am able to output all quotes now, when using the parameter orderby="random" i now have  unique quotes most of the time but sometimes duplicate ones for there are still to {exp:stash:get_list}. Do you have any more ideas how two prevent duplicate quotes. I now have this sofar and can't quite comprehend the slice offset parameters for Stash yet.                                   {exp:stash:get_list name="quotes" unique="yes" orderby="random"}

Comment: Updated my original answer. Note: Your `unique="yes"` tag is only relevant to returning unique content within the list. Calling it every iteration does not look at what it out put last iteration.